# Can spiders swim against current?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.4_01 if I have a vertical wall standing on dirt with a water source block placed where the wall and ground meet (see below) can spiders (or any mob for that matter) even reach the wall?

C = Cobblestone
D = Dirt
W = Water Source

> C
>   C
>   C
>   C
>   CW
>   DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

For the sake of simplicity I've intentionally not listed flowing water.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, mobs cannot move fast enough to fight a current. However, this is rumored to change in a later patch.

Comment: Links to rumors?

Comment: Or the source of your information if you haven't personally tested this?

Comment: It's just from personal testing, this isn't really a hard one to prove. As for the rumors, I only remember hearing them.

Comment: Good enough for me.

Comment: My initial hidey hole  had a river flowing out of half of it, and nothing has ever made it in.